# Fragment still displayed on screen when back key while refreshing with SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, fragment

I have an activity with 2 fragments: A and B. currently A was added on activity. After click a button:

```
ft.replace(containerId, B, tag);
ft.addToBackStack("A");
ft.commit();
```

B was displayed and A was removed normally.
Pull to refresh and press back while the progress is loading:

```
// this is implementation in OnBackPressed()
....
int backStackEntryCount = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
if (backStackEntryCount > 0) {
    fm.popBackStackImmediate();
}
....
```

**The problem is fragment B still displayed on screen (blank) and overlap fragment A, if back again app will exit**. Some information about B:

- I implemented SwipeRefreshLayout on B
- Here is B source code:

  ```
  public class B extends MyFragment {

  protected View view;
  protected ListView listView;
  protected ImageView progress;
  protected TextView notifText;
  protected LayoutInflater inflater;
  protected PTRBaseAdapter adapter;
  protected SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

  protected String emptyText;
  protected boolean fromRest;
  protected int loads = 0;
  protected float mPreviousX = 0;
  protected float mPreviousY = 0;

  protected void doRefresh(boolean fromRest) {
      if (!isAdded()) return;
      notifText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      fetchFromDatabase();
      if (fromRest) {
          refresh();
      }
  }

  private void fetchFromDatabase() {
      /* fetch data from db here and got the "list" */
      adapter = new EventAdapter(list);
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
      loads++;
      if (adapter.getCount() == 0) {
          notifText.setText(R.string.NoEvents);
          notifText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      } else {
          notifText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
  }

  private void refresh() {
      if (!isAdded()) return;
      GenericManager.getInstance().fetchEvents(mContext, new OnFinished() {
          @Override
          public void onFinished(boolean result) {
              if (result) {
                  if (isAdded() && getActivity() != null) {
                      fetchFromDatabase();
                      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      listView.invalidate();
                      mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                  }
              }
          }
      });
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ptr_list, container, false);
      this.inflater = inflater;
      mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
      mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.md_material_blue_600);

      listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.pull_refresh_list);
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(mOnItemClickListener);
      listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
          @Override
          public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
              boolean enable = false;
              if (listView != null && listView.getChildCount() > 0) {
                  boolean firstItemVisible = (listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0);
                  boolean topOfFirstItemVisible = (listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0);
                  enable = firstItemVisible && topOfFirstItemVisible;
              }
              mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(enable);
          }
      });

      mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
          @Override
          public void onRefresh() {
              refresh();
          }
      });

      progress = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
      progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

      notifText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notifText);
      notifText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

              int action = event.getActionMasked();
              float x = event.getX();
              float y = event.getY();

              switch (action) {
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                      break;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                      float dx = x - mPreviousX;
                      float dy = y - mPreviousY;

                      if (dy > 300) {
                          mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                                  doRefresh(fromRest);
                              }
                          });
                      }
                      break;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                      break;
              }
              mPreviousX = x;
              mPreviousY = y;
              return true;
          }
      });

      setTopbarTitle();
      return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
      doRefresh(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void setTopbarTitle() {
      topbar = (TopBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.topbar);
      topbarTitle = R.string.Events;
      ((MyActivity) getActivity()).setTabBarVisibility(false);
      topbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      super.setTopbarTitle();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
      doRefresh(false);
      super.onResume();
  }

  /* The adapter for list but I think it does not affect anything */
  ```

And in MyFragment I have override onDettach:

```
  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Layout of fragment B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/viewstyle">

        <com.myapp.viewcomp.TopBar
            android:id="@+id/topbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/progress" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/pull_refresh_list"
            style="@style/ptr_style"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:divider="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/topbar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notifText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/progress"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I dont know why **the fragment B went to onDetach but it still freezed on screen, I can see a little bit of A fragment at the bottom**. Any suggestion is really really appreciated, I stucked at this thing about few days :(

I think the problem is in the implementation of B fragment but I cant figure it out, not sure the problem is from SwipeRefreshLayout or not ...

Comment: since you are adding the replace transaction to backstack how about just letting android take care of backpress and you remove your code from onBackPressed

Comment: if I let super.OnBackPressed(), application will exit right after click back button and that snip code in OnBackPressed work for many cases from others fragment on my activity so I cant remove it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved problem myself with**

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Comment: try onDestroy()